# search the line in a file for a number after a particular word and iterate over that number

Tags: python, iteration

I have a file with multiple lines and one of them read as: loop_iter 10 {apples=0; oranges=0}

```
import sys
import re

input_file = open(r'C:\infile')
pat_file_read = input_file.read()

for line in input_file_read:
    match = re.search("loop_iter\s*(\d+)" , input_file_read)
    print match.group(1)
```

right now I am able to print it as many times as there lines in the file and if I do

```
for line in input_file_read:
    if line.startswith("loop_iter"):
    match = re.search("loop_iter\s*(\d+)" , input_file_read)
    print match.group(1)
```

Does not work...

Answer (score 1):

The syntax coloring here in Stack Overflow might have given you a hint already... But it looks like your quote marks don't match:

```
if line.startswith('loop_iter"):
```

Try

```
if line.startswith("loop_iter"):
```

Comment: I did try that. I made a syntax error but edited the question now. The loop_iter starts after many white spaces.. May be I should consider the white spaces too??

Comment: Are you "reading" the file twice, in two different loops? If so, then you need to reset the file pointer back to the beginning via `seek(0)`.

Comment: No I am not reading it twice. That is pretty much the entire code I have so far.

Comment: Is there a way I can iterate over the number in a line?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got it to work once I converted the match.group(1) into an integer.

```
import sys
import re

input_file = open(r'C:\infile')
pat_file_read = input_file.read()

for line in input_file_read:
    match = re.search("loop_iter\s*(\d+)" , input_file_read)
    i = int(match.group(1))

for x in range i:
    print 'something'
```